# Set a variable value from listbox in C#

Tags: c#, variables, listbox

I want to know how could I set a variable value from list box in C#

For example;

Variable X = listbox item 9

Or Variable Y = listbox item 12

thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by variable value? Do you want to set the value of the selected item in the list box to a variable?

Comment: Yeah,as i said in the example i want to set my first variable(X for example) to my 9th listbox item - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("9");
        listBox1.Items.Add("15");
        listBox1.Items.Add("27");

        int x = int.Parse(listBox1.Items[0].ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = int.Parse(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could use `listBox1.SelectedItems[1].ToString()`if you wish to store it as a string. Or simply use .SelectedItems to access the item your looking to store and then store it in a variable

Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a listbox named `lbxRole`

To **set** a value to the 9th item you can do something like this:

```
if(lbxRoles.Count > 9)        // Make sure the listbox has 9 items (else it'll throw an exception)
{
    string x = "test item";
    lbxRoles.Items[9] = x;    // Set value of x to the 9th item
}
```

To **get** the value of the 9th Item you can do something like this:

```
object x = lbxRole.Items[9];
```

In most cases, the listbox will contain a string, so you might want to do something like this instead:

```
string selected_item = lbxRole.Items[9].ToString();
```

*`ListBox`es have an `Items` property. It is basically a collection of all the items that the `ListBox` holds. To access all the items you can just use `lbxRoles.Items` as a normal Collection.

To access all the selected items you can use `lbxRoles.SelectedItems`. To use the first selected item, you use `lbx.SelectedItem`.*